# Sorting an array

Tags: performance

I want to know which is better to sort an **array of elements**.

Is it better to get good performance to sort the array at the end when I finish filling it? Or it is better to sort it each time I add an element to it?

Comment: what kind of array are we talking about,  10 items, 1 million items?

Comment: "Or it is better to sort it each time I add an element to it?" - Sounds a bit like an insertion sort no?

Comment: What language is this? PHP, HTML, Javascript?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: it is between 10k to 100K  ... I am reading from CSV file and trying to create an array for each column in the SCV file so that, next calculations would be faster after i sort these  arrays. Each time i read a line, i push the column value in the array. I am using javascript language here

Comment: let me make sure I got this right, you have a CSV file that you are reading with Javascript and will take those values and place them into a javascript array, in and have them sorted in some fashion to make the next set of calculations faster?  I want to be sure I got this right

Comment: yes that's right Kenneth.

Comment: Yes.  And no.  It depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the application-specific information for a moment, consider that sorted insertion requires, worst case, O(n) operations for each element.  For n elements, this of course gives us O(n^2).  If this sounds familiar, it's because what you're doing is (as another commenter pointed out) an insertion sort.  In contrast, performing one quicksort on the entire list will take, worse case, O(n log n) time.

So, does this mean you should definitely wait until the end to sort?  No.  The important thing to remember is that O(n log n) is the best we can do for sorting in the **general** case.  Your application-speciifc knowledge of the data can influence the best algorithm for the job.  For example, if you know your data is already almost sorted, then insertion sort will give you linear time complexity.

Your mileage may vary, but I think the algorithmic viewpoint is useful when examining the general problem of "When should I sort?"

Comment: thanks David. As the data are almost random, i think i will sort arrays at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is critical to you. Do you need to be able to insert very fast (a lot of entries but little queries) or do you need to be able to query very fast and insert slowly (a lot of queries but not many entries) ?

This is basically your problem to solve. When you know this you can select an appropriate sorting algorithm and apply it.

Edit: This is assuming that either choice actually matters. This depends a lot on your activity (inserts vs queries) and the amount of data that you need to sort.

Comment: Please explain the downvote. I will remove or correct my answer as needed.

Comment: i need to deal with csv file (10k to 100K), then create an array for each column in the csv file. then counting values in each array and use these counting later.